# ASP.NET update panel doesn't update until second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've looked for answers online but there are so many that I've tried that haven't worked. I have two buttons on the page a "like" and a "dislike" button.

When I click on a button the updatepanel doesn't update but the like data for that user is inserted into the database.

When I click on the button the second time the update panel gets refreshed and works for proceeding clicks. I want the update panel to refresh on the first click

```
<form id="Matches" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="VotePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div class="row">
              <!-- left column -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                       ail" />
                            <h1>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h1>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Like" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Dislike" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />

                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" />
                </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# Code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uservote.spAddLike(user.getId(), usermatch.getId());
            VotePanel.Update();

        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uservote.spAddDislike(user.getId(), usermatch.getId());
            VotePanel.Update();
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you set `ChildenAsTriggers` to true? Also what are you changing and how are you canging the contents of the update panel? Is there something in `uservote.spAddLike`?

Comment: Does the script manager need to be outside of the form?

Comment: @JonP The same thing when I set `ChildenAsTriggers` to true. I have another stored procedure that gets another user. This is at the top of the `Page_Load`

Comment: There is your problem. `Page_load` is called before click event. I'll elaborate in a an answer.

Comment: @JasonW I think so. I followed a tutorial and they said to put it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments in addtion to your question, you are calling an update function **before** you have updated the database. You need to get a better understanding of the [page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You are getting a the updated info on page load, this happens before the on click. Try the following

```
 private void functionToUpdateFields(some arguements)
 {
      /*Call Database and populate form fields*/
 }


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!isPostback)
     {
         functionToUpdateFields(some arguements);
     }
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        uservote.spAddLike(user.getId(), usermatch.getId());
        functionToUpdateFields(some arguements);
        VotePanel.Update();
 }

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       uservote.spAddDislike(user.getId(), usermatch.getId());
       functionToUpdateFields(some arguements);
       VotePanel.Update();
 }
```

When you have all this set up set break poins on each of the event handlers and note the order in which they occur when you debug. This will give you a practical demonstration on the page life cycle.

Comment: In response to your suggested edit, by removing `!isPostback` you will make two database calls instead of one and update the fields twice. This suggests something else is not right with your code.

Comment: If I leave in `!IsPostBack` null values get inserted into the database and the page doesn't refresh. I inserted `<p>><%=DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay%></p>` so I can see when the page updates.
I understand what is happening with your code. For the `Page_Load` load you only want `functionToUpdateFields(some arguements);` to get updated once and for the buttons to update the page the remaining times.